# I can't get this text inside my div with border work

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 900px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . </div>
```

Hello , I can't seem to make this div work properly. I don't want this text to get out of this div like it is doing right now. Is there any solution for this? I've already tried setting word-break:break-all; and  overflow-wrap: break-word;  but none of those worked. Any advice is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you use border-radius, the browser does not take this into account, it still will render it as a rectangle, the radius is just visual.

You could correct it using padding like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 900px;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . </div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding` to `div`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 900px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . </div>
```

Comment: that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow:hidden` and add some padding in it...

```css
* {margin: 0;}

div {
  background-color:green;
  height:900px;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . </div>
```